# Why cant we use Any or Nothing in scala pattern matching?

Tags: scala, case

I noticed that in the following circumstances, the scala type "Int" can be used, but Any or Nothing, cannot.

```
user match {
case Int => "scala int"
case Any => "?"
}
```

How and why does scala's case class differentiate between these types as being *matchable*?

Comment: When you write `case Int =>` you're probably not getting what you expect. It'll only match the `Int` companion object, which provides e.g. `Int.MaxValue`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is not really a type at all (there exist no instances of this type - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.Nothing). To match Any you can just use _

Answer (score 1):

If you write it correctly:

```
user match {
  case _: Int => "scala int"
  case _: Any => "?"
}
```

you can use `Any` (though it isn't useful, as Eugene points out). You can't use `Nothing` because it could never match.